# Is there an eclipse WTP plugin for jQuery development?

Tags: ide, jquery, eclipse, plugins

I'm just starting out working with jQuery, so I'm using eclipse because it's what I have installed (I use it for the pydev plugin currently). I added the WTP plugin which seems cool, but the jQuery support is noticeably lacking.

What plugins does the community recommend, or if none, what editors are you using for jQuery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A plugin for JDST (Eclipse JavaScript Development Tools) that adds jQuery autocompletion support.

[JSDT jQuery 1.0.2](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/jsdt-jquery)